# Continue multi-host tests even on failure

Tags: ruby, serverspec

I've built some serverspec code to run a group of tests on multiple hosts. The trouble is that the testing stops at the current host when any test fails. I want it to continue to all hosts even if a test fails.

The Rakefile:

```
namespace :spec do
  task :all => hosts.map {|h| 'spec:' + h.split('.')[0] }
  hosts.each do |host|
    begin
      desc "Run serverspec to #{host}"
      RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(host) do |t|
        ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = host
        t.pattern = "spec/cfengine3/*_spec.rb"
      end
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```

Complete code:
https://gist.github.com/neilhwatson/1d41c696102c01bbb87a

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by [RSpec::Core::RakeTask#fail_on_error](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/RakeTask:fail_on_error) so in order to have it continue on all hosts you need to add `t.fail_on_error = false`. I also think that you don't need to `rescue`.

```
namespace :spec do
  task :all => hosts.map {|h| 'spec:' + h.split('.')[0] }
  hosts.each do |host|
    desc "Run serverspec to #{host}"
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(host) do |t|
      ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = host
      t.pattern = "spec/cfengine3/*_spec.rb"
      t.fail_on_error = false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Setting `t.fail_on_error = false` also causes rake to always return an exit code of 0 to the calling process. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a `continue_on_error` or similar method to ensure that all tasks run, and failures are still reported on finish.